# Javascript - Promises and forEach

Tags: javascript, promise, sails.js

I am trying to fill the array with avatarIcon node from parsed xmls but my final array in res.view is empty plus the execution doesn't seem to reach return res.view function. How do I do this correctly?

```
function parseXML(xml) {
 var parsed
 parseString(xml, { explicitArray: false }, function(err, result) {
     parsed = result
 })
 return parsed
}

function findUsers() {
 return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    User.find().exec(function(err, sids) {
        resolve(sids)
    })
 })
}

avatars: function(req, res) {
    var arr = []
    findUsers().then(function(result) {
        result.forEach(function(el) {
            getProfileXML(el.sid).then(function(result) {
                 arr.push(parseXML(result).profile.avatarIcon)
            })

        })
        return res.view('users', {
            users: arr
        })

    })

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to wrap a collection of promises. Here untested code to demonstrate the use, where the result of the expression is a promise too:

```js
return findUsers().then(function(result) {

  var promises = result.map(function(el) {
    return getProfileXML(el.sid);
  });
  return Promise.all(promises);

}).then(function(values) {
  var arr = values.map(function(v) {
    return parseXML(v).profile.avatarIcon;
  });
  return res.view('users', {
    users: arr
  })
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you saved me from this trouble.